# how to use google calender for appointments on website

Tags: wordpress, google-calendar-api

My client want me to add Google Calender on his website to make the appointments. And the Client can view these appointments into his Google calender and add notes on it. And the added notes of that appointment should be visible on the appointees profile on the website, I am looking for the plugins on wordpress to implement it. I am getting plugins for the event manager and a few for appointment but do not getting the plugin which uses Google calender for the appointment . Please help me out, I would be pleased if any suggestion provided by u all.

Comment: A Google search (!) gave me this.  https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link exectly what you are loking for

Video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=X0wB9jtyRQU

WWD : http://gigaom.com/2011/06/07/wwd-screencast-how-to-use-google-calendar-appointment-slots/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion  these links provides the information about how to make appointments . But it was only for the staff to create an appointment. but according to my clients requirements he wants that the visitor can also make an appointment from the website  and that appointment should save in google calender, so i will be very much kindfull to u if u suggest any plugin which merges google calender into it and fullfill the requirement as do.                  i have done googling but cant find any of the plugin in free version  all are in paid versions which support google merging.